# Write a function using pattern test to test whether the input is polynomial and print error message if not

Tags: pattern-matching, polynomials

I am doing this which is supposed to be an easy problem and which I think my code should be correct but for some reasons it is not working. May anyone help correcting my mistakes? How should I write the correct code?

This is the question:

> Write a function that takes a polynomial in the variable x as input and computes its degree. Using a pattern test your function should print an error message when the input is not a polynomial. (It is acceptable if your function regards a string object such as "Math" as a polynomial of degree zero).

My answer:

```
If[Function[y, PolynomialQ[y, x]][x^2 + 3 x], Exponent[y, x], Print["error"]]
```

My code always returns zero and I have no idea why. Also, do we have to use Function[] to write a function?

Many thanks in advance for all the helps!

Edit:
Thanks @0x4A4D for suggestion.
Here is my edited code:

```
If[Function[x, PolynomialQ[x^2, x]], Exponent[y, x], Print["error"]]
```

which I think doesn't quite make any sense, the code does not even produce any output. I guess something is wrong with Function[], but not sure how. I would be grateful if anyone could lend some help. I have been doing this question for quite a long time. Thanks!

Comment: `PolynomialQ[]` is intended to be used directly; that is,  `PolynomialQ[x^2 + 3 x, x]`. `Exponent[y, x]` is necessarily $0$; I see no `x` whatsoever in the first argument...

Comment: @0x4A4D. Thanks for the advice for PolynomialQ, but how then can we compute the degree and what do you mean by no x in first argument? Thanks.

Comment: There's no `x` in `y`, last I checked... if you'd assigned `y` to something with `x` in it, like `y = x^2 + 3 x;`, then you're cooking.

Comment: To push you in the right direction: `polynomialDegree[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := (* stuff *)`.

Comment: This is as far as I can get: polynomialdegree[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := Exponent[poly, x]. But I cannot print an error message if it is not a polynomial? Should I use If instead, then how can I do it?

Comment: Indeed, you should be using `If[]` in the definition. You almost had it. What you can do is to remove the `/; PolynomialQ[poly, x]` part and move the check within the `If[]`.

Comment: @0x4A4D. I will try to give an answer below, hopefully it is correct. hmm.. lets see

Answer (score 4):

There's a bit of a trick that lets you do this with a single definition:

```
fun::notpoly = "Not a polynomial!!!"
fun[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] || Message[fun::notpoly] :=
  something[poly];
```

This works because the test clause has to be `True` for the rule to fire, and `Message` returns `Null`.

Comment: emit a message and return unevaluated all in one function call, nice. +1

Comment: Although, strictly speaking, it doesn't use a `PatternTest`, but `Conditional`.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
test::wronginp = "test accepts only polynomials as input.";
test[func_?(PolynomialQ[#, x] &)] := "Degree" (* replace with actual degree Determination*)
test[___] := (Message[test::wronginp]; $Failed )
```

Some tests:

```
test[x^2 + 1]
```

> "Degree"

```
test[Sin[x]]
```

> During evaluation of In[535]:= test::wronginp: test accepts only polynomials as input.
>
> $Failed

Comment: `Abort[]` here could be bad, especially if buried in a deeper calculation. Why not return `$Failed`, instead? Although, the usual case is to return unevaluated.

Comment: @rcollyer Good Point. Changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to 0x4A4D and Markus Roellig for the helps.

This is what I have tried, using built-in functions PolynomialQ and Exponent and an If statement.

```
dop[f_] := If[PolynomialQ[f, x], d = Exponent[f, x]; Print[d], Print["ERROR"]]
```

Comments are welcomed, let me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: 1. It would be best if you can make `dop` take the variable as another argument, in addition to the polynomial. 2. Replace `d = Exponent[f, x]; Print[d]` with just `Exponent[f, x]`; it should still work fine.

Comment: As @0x4A4D mentioned already,in most cases, you don't need `Print` to output the result. *Matheamtica* will automatically output the result when finishing evaluation.